# fork() causes the beginning of the parent's main to execute if shell output is piped somewhere

Tags: c, unix, fork

I was trying to use the `fork()` function, but I'm getting some strange behavior. Part (not all) of the main function of the parent process is seemingly run right after `fork()` is called, but only if the output of the executable is piped somewhere on the command line.

I noticed this on Mac OS Mojave, but I have tested the same code on Ubuntu 18.04, which exhibits the same behavior. I have no idea why this is happening.

Here is the test code in the file `fork.c`:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void)
{
        pid_t child_pid;
        printf("Beginning of main for process %d\n", getpid());
        if ((child_pid = fork())) {
                printf("Forked process %d\n", child_pid);
        } else {
                printf("Beginning of forked process %d\n", getpid());
        }
}
```

And here is a shell session using this code:

```sh
 $ cc fork.c
 $ ./a.out
Beginning of main for process 98373
Forked process 98374
Beginning of forked process 98374
 $ ./a.out | cat
Beginning of main for process 98378
Forked process 98380
Beginning of main for process 98378
Beginning of forked process 98380
```

As you can see above, the statement at the beginning of `main()` is executed twice in the parent process if the output is piped somewhere.

Comment: `stdout` is normally line-buffered but fully buffered if connected to a pipe. Call `fflush(NULL)` before `fork` and it would work as you expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has to do with I/O buffering.

The console is line buffered by default, so if your output string ends in a newline and you don't redirect, the output is flushed right away.  But when you redirect stdout a newline doesn't flush the buffer.  So when you fork both the parent and the child have a line  of text in the output buffer so the both print the first line.

You can fix this by explicitly flushing the buffer with `fflush`.

```
printf("Beginning of main for process %d\n", getpid());
flush(stdout);
```